# Refactor multiple if condition in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I want to refactor this code but am wondering how I should start it. I'm not sure this code is totally against clean code or not. I'm thinking to use RxJS or a JavaScript builtin method. I'd like to have some help here to learn how to have clean code or how I can minimize the code to few line or chain multiple method of RxJS or JS to get rid of if conditions.

```
public loadChart(): void {
    this.chartDataSets = [];
    let allData = this.availableDataSet;
    if(this.selectedAttribute === Dashbaord.All && this.selectedComponent === Dashbaord.All) {
    this.prepareIntialData();
}
if (this.selectedAttribute === Dashbaord.All && this.selectedComponent !== Dashbaord.All) {
    const groupedByComponent = this.pendingActionDataSet.groupByArray(x => x.component);
    allData = groupedByComponent[this.selectedComponent];
}
if (this.selectedAttribute !== Dashbaord.All && this.selectedComponent === Dashbaord.All) {
    allData = this.groupedByAttribute[this.selectedAttribute].flattenArray();//["",""]
    const components = allData.groupByArray(x => x.component);//["key":["values"]]
    this.componentOptions = Mapper.mapToSelectItemWithAll(Object.keys(components)); 
}
if (this.selectedAttribute !== Dashbaord.All && this.selectedComponent !== Dashbaord.All) {
    const allDataByAttribute = this.groupedByAttribute[this.selectedAttribute].flattenArray();
    const groupedByComponent = allDataByAttribute.groupByArray(x => x.component);
    this.componentOptions = Mapper.mapToSelectItemWithAll(Object.keys(groupedByComponent));
    if (!this.componentOptions.filter(x => x.value === this.selectedComponent).length) {
        this.selectedComponent = Dashbaord.All;
        allData = allDataByAttribute;
    } else {
        allData = groupedByComponent[this.selectedComponent];
    }
}
this.prepareChartData(allData);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Indentation** Your current indentation is a bit confusing - the function's opening block's `{` line is not balanced with the closing block `}` line. At a glance, it looks like the function is 4 lines long, and like there's an extra `}` at the very bottom of the snippet. Consider using an IDE which can prettily format code automatically, such as VSCode - it makes things much easier when you and anyone who reads the code can identify each block and its nesting level at a glance.

**Spelling** Spelling matters in programming - misspellings are a very common cause of bugs. `Dashbaord` should probably be renamed to `Dashboard`, rather than using the misspelled word everywhere (which would probably eventually cause a headache or few, especially if other developers have to go over the code).

**Prefer `const`** - [don't use `let`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6) unless you must reassign the variable name. Using `const` makes code more readable when you know there's no chance of the variable name being reassigned. Here, rather than reassigning the `allData` variable name, you may refactor to `const` by calling `prepareChartData` immediately, rather than reassign `allData`. For example:

```
if (this.selectedAttribute === Dashbaord.All && this.selectedComponent !== Dashbaord.All) {
    const groupedByComponent = this.pendingActionDataSet.groupByArray(x => x.component);
    allData = groupedByComponent[this.selectedComponent];
}
```

can turn into

```
if (this.selectedAttribute === Dashbaord.All && this.selectedComponent !== Dashbaord.All) {
    const groupedByComponent = this.pendingActionDataSet.groupByArray(x => x.component);
    this.prepareChartData(groupedByComponent[this.selectedComponent]);
}
```

If you don't like repeating `this.prepareChartData` everywhere, you could make it a bit shorter with:

```
// replace Data with the appropriate type below:
const prepareData = (data: Data) => {
  this.prepareChartData(data);
};
```

**Comparisons** As for your `if` statements, you can save the two comparisons being done in variables first, then use those variables:

```
const { All } = Dashboard; // note spelling
const attribIsAll = this.selectedAttribute === All;
const selectedIsAll = this.selectedComponent === All;
if (attribIsAll && selectedIsAll) {
  // ...
} else if (attribIsAll && !selectedIsAll) {
  // ...
```

Another option would be to group one of the truthy comparisons together, like so:

```
if (attribIsAll) {
  if (selectedIsAll) {
    this.prepareIntialData();
  } else {
    const groupedByComponent = this.pendingActionDataSet.groupByArray(x => x.component);
    prepareData(groupedByComponent[this.selectedComponent]);
  }
  return; // return early; avoid dense indentation later
}
if (selectedIsAll) {
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```

**Array test** You have

```
if (!this.componentOptions.filter(x => x.value === this.selectedComponent).length) {
```

In general, if you want to check that no elements in an array satisfy a condition, it would be more semantically appropriate to use `.some` or `.every`:

```
const componentOptionSelected = this.componentOptions.some(
  option => option.value === this.selectedComponent
);
if (componentOptionSelected) {
  prepareData(groupedByComponent[this.selectedComponent]);
} else {
  this.selectedComponent = Dashboard.All; // note spelling
  prepareData(allDataByAttribute);
}
```